# Jade unexpected token error

Tags: syntax, undefined, pug

I'm new to jade and kind of stuck with this error. Greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

```
 section.page_intro
            .page_intro_body.effect2
              h1 Bangkok Tours & Daytrips
              h2 Daytrips and Tour Packages in Bangkok
              //
                Social
              #social
```

---

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
1446|           section.page_intro
1447|             .page_intro_body.effect2
```

> 1448|               h1 Bangkok Tours & Daytrips
>       1449|               h2 Daytrips and Tour Packages in Bangkok
>       1450|               #social
>       1451|                 .fb_like

Unexpected token `attrs` expected `text`, `code`, `:`, `newline` or `eos`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Problem solved after removing the fb integration #social then added back later after compile.